# Eventhough function is declared payable , getting this error:The called function should be payable if you send value

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, payable

I am new to Solidity and can't understand why I am getting the above error even though the function purchaseProduct() is declared as payable. I tried this code on Remix IDE and got this error.
**VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the transaction to get more information.**
Everything is working fine except for the purchaseProduct() function. I am trying to fetch the data from struct 'User', 'Product' and strore the data in a new struct that is 'Order'.
I have carried out validation using require().
While  running the code on Remix:
1. Create 2 users
2. Create Product using first user
and then,
3. purchaseProduct using second user

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

//Address: '0x7772B9117586b5F745bDb563a935E91b00449157'

contract Buyproduct{

    uint public orderCount = 0;
    mapping(uint => Order) public orders;

    uint public productCount = 0;
    mapping(uint => Product) public products;

    uint public userCount = 0;
    mapping(address => User) public users;

    struct Order {
        uint oid;
        address payable seller;
        address payable buyer;
      //  string timestamp;
        string status;
        uint pid;
        string location;
        uint quantitiy;
    }

    struct Product {
        uint pid;
        string name;
        uint price;
        address payable seller;

        string info;
        uint quantity;
    }

    struct User {
        uint uid;
        string name;
        uint role;
        address payable user;
        string location;
        bool created;
    }

    event ProductCreated(
        uint pid,
        string name,
        uint price,
        address payable seller,
        string info,
        uint quantity
    );

    event  UserCreated(
        uint uid,
        string name,
        uint role,
        address payable user,
        string location,
        bool created
    );

    event ProductPurchased(
        uint oid,
        address payable seller,
        address payable buyer,
        string status,
        uint pid,
        string location,
        uint quantity
    );

    event ReviewAdded(
        uint rid,
        address reviewer,
        uint pid,
        string review
    );

    function createUser(string memory _name, uint _role, string memory _location) public payable{
        //No repeated address
        require(users[msg.sender].created == false, 'User already created');
        //Increase userCount
        userCount++;
        //Add user
        users[msg.sender] = User(userCount, _name, _role, msg.sender, _location, true);
        //Trigger an event
        emit UserCreated(userCount, _name, _role, msg.sender, _location, true);
    }

    function createProduct(string memory _name, uint _price, string memory _info, uint _quantity) public payable {
        // Require a valid price
        require(_price > 0, 'Invalid Price');
        // Increment product count
        productCount ++;
        // Create the product
        products[productCount] = Product(productCount, _name, _price, msg.sender, _info, _quantity);
        // Trigger an event
        emit ProductCreated(productCount, _name, _price, msg.sender, _info, _quantity);
    }

    function purchaseProduct(uint _id, /*string memory timestamp,*/ uint _quantity) public payable {
        // Fetch the product
        Product memory _product = products[_id];
        // Fetch the owner
        address payable _seller = _product.seller;
        //Validate the buyer
        require(users[msg.sender].created == true, 'Unregistered user');
        // Make sure the product has a valid id
        require(_product.pid > 0 && _product.pid <= productCount, 'Invalid Product ID');
        // Require that there is enough Ether in the transaction
        require(msg.value >= _product.price, 'Not enough ether in Wallet');
        // Require that the buyer is not the seller
        require(_seller != msg.sender,'Invalid Purchase');
        //Incrmement orderCount
        orderCount++;
        // Transfer ownership to the buyer
        orders[orderCount] = Order(orderCount, _seller, msg.sender,/* ts,*/ 'Ordered', _product.pid, users[msg.sender].location, _quantity);
        //Reduce the quantity of the product
        _product.quantity -= _quantity;
        // Pay the contract by sending them Ether
        address payable wallet = address(uint160(address(this)));
        wallet.transfer(msg.value);
        // Trigger an event
        emit ProductPurchased(orderCount, _seller, msg.sender, /*timestamp,*/ 'Ordered', _product.pid, users[msg.sender].location, _quantity);
    }


}'''
```

Comment: The error comes when calling the function purchaseProduct() in remix

Comment: Sorry, What is the error you are getting while calling purchaseProduct(), Please post the error message too.

Comment: I have edited and added the error message in bold. The bold part is the output I am getting in console.

Answer (score 1):

```
    function createProduct(string memory _name, uint _price, string memory _info, uint _quantity) public payable {
```

This function signature has _price in ethers.
So try changing the default units to the ether from Wei and send the appropriate price of the product. 
[image]

Mine is working

```
[vm]from:0x4b0...4d2dbto:Buyproduct.purchaseProduct(uint256,uint256) 0x1df...bda71value:2000000000000000000 weidata:0xa04...00001logs:1hash:0x4e0...0d2b0
```

You also don't need to call these explicitly.

```
address payable wallet = address(uint160(address(this)));
wallet.transfer(msg.value);
```

Contract balance will be updated automatically. You can check by implementing this function on your contract.

```
    function getBalance()
             public 
             view 
             returns(uint) {
                return address(this).balance;}
```

Comment: Still getting the error

Comment: What was your product value? and whats the value you are sending from your registered user?

Comment: The values I am passing for the function are _id=1 and _quantity=1 alongwith value=3 eth